# mutliple nodes in GameScene.sks with same name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, contacts, skspritenode

I'm trying to make a simple 2D Platformer game. Instead of importing the sprites, I decided to use the ones the SpriteKit engine provides: in GameScene.sks I dragged and dropped a sprite (simple, red square) which I called "wall". I copied and pasted it to have 2 walls the player could jump on. In the code part I wrote the following lines:

```
var wall = SKSpriteNode()
```

and then, in the "didMoveToView" function:

```
    wall = self.childNodeWithName("wall") as! SKSpriteNode
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall.size)
    wall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    wall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    wall.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.wall
    wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.player
```

since I've created a struct outside the class ("physicsCategories") holding the various categories bit masks, when I check for contacts it works just fine:

```
 //CONTACT
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case physicsCategories.player | physicsCategories.wall:
        isGrounded = true
    default:
        print("Some other contact")
    }
}
```

My problem is that this works only with one of the 2 sprites with the name "wall". Is there a way to reference in code ALL the sprites in the scene which have that same name? Like a tag or something like "self.childrenNodesWithName(...)", which I know doesn't exist unluckly.
Or maybe am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a class like 'class Wall: SKSpriteNode' and then reference it in the wall object inside GameScene.sks

Comment: thanks for the tip. But I'm not sure how to reference a class from an object in GameScene.sks, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not my mac with me, this is a screenshot from the web:

[image]

Comment: I don't have that feature in my GameScene.sks. May this be due to the fact that I'm not using the latest version of Xcode (I'm on 6.4)? If that's the case, it's a bit problematic, since I can't manage to update to OSX El Capitan (I posted a question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1063825/issue-upgrading-from-osx-yosemite-to-el-capitan-10-11-4-on-imac  but stil I couldn't solve the issue). In the meantime I've written this code:

Comment: Sorry, I don't know from which version is available

Comment: Oh okay. Can you help me then with this other way? Now I've created an array of walls and with "for child in self.children" I check if the name of the child is "wall" and then append it to the array. This way seems to work but: A) I'm not sure this is "good code" B) I'm very interested in doing it your way (which doesn't seem to be an option for me though). Do you think my method is ok? Thanks again for the help you're providing

Comment: It's working with your way? But you "wall" do some special func? By your code you can set the same property directly by the sks file

Comment: Yes apparently it is working. The wall has a physics body and some characteristics which I had to exclude from my comment because I had no characters left. I was wondering if it was a good way to work around that project

Comment: sincerely I don't know, before I used only code, and now I'm using the sks file with custom class. But I think that search every time all the child is not good. If you put different name like wall1 wall2 etc?

Comment: I thought it was better because I don't think it's okay to write many many lines just to give practically identical sprites the same specs. But still, as you say, that search shouldn't be good. Anyway as soon as I can use my other computer with the latest version of Xcode I'll try your way which sounds like it's the best.